# HTML Popup Database Actions

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, database, html

I'm working on a collection of points on the map, each comes with a bunch of properties. I succeeded using a customized XSL template to show the information when I click on any point. And now what I wanna achieve is to add a "next" & "previous" button in the window, which navigates to the information of next adjacent point. I don't know if this idea is possible at all, or do I have to write a add-in for this function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: next adjacent point, in which direction?

Comment: Doesn't matter, as long as it's the next item in the attribute table

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823842/select-the-next-element-with-a-specific-attribute-jquery

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132219/xslt-current-previous-next